# Large Delay in Serial Read from Arduino to Processing

Tags: arduino, serial-port, sprite, processing

I am having trouble getting my sketch to respond to my ardunio in actual time. There is about a 30 second delay. The delay gets longer as the sketch continues to run.

My goal: under certain conditions from the Arduino a sprite will play in processing. There are 4 condition (1 0, 1 1, 2 0, 2 1).

Code:

```
int numFrames = 7;
int currentFrame = 0;
PImage[] images = new PImage[numFrames];


import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;  
String val;     


void setup() {
  size(1000,600);
  frameRate(5);

  images[0]  = loadImage("images/heart(1).gif");
  images[1]  = loadImage("images/heart(2).gif"); 
  images[2]  = loadImage("images/heart(3).gif");
  images[3]  = loadImage("images/heart(4).gif");
  images[4]  = loadImage("images/heart(5).gif");
  images[5]  = loadImage("images/heart(6).gif");
  images[6]  = loadImage("images/heart(7).gif");



String portName = Serial.list()[1]; 
myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600); 
} 

void draw() { 
    background(255);

 //Display Serial Data 
 if (myPort.available() > 0) {
    if ( (val = myPort.readStringUntil(ENTER)) != null )  val = trim(val);
    else return;
    if (val != null) {
    println(val);
    }
  }


//control sketch
  currentFrame = (currentFrame+1) % numFrames;  // Use % to cycle through       frames
```

int offset = 0;

```
if ("1 1".equals(val)) {
image(images[(currentFrame+offset) % numFrames], 333, 200);
offset+=2;
```

}

```
if("2 1".equals(val)){
image(images[(currentFrame+offset) % numFrames], 666, 200);
offset+=2;
player.play();
}
```

}

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you also post the arduino code. Do you get the same delays when you see the text via Serial Monitor in Arduino ?

Comment: Looking at the code again, there isn't much that should delay it other than the ```frameRate(5);``` line. If ```trim()``` doesn't remove the space at the centre of the command (e.g. "1 1" arrives as "1 1", not "11"), there shouldn't be a delay, at least on the Processing side. Please also post the Arduino code, otherwise it will be impossible to tell what the exact issue is